# How do I simulate table row width percentages with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

It may not be obvious from this that I am trying to create something like the table below:

http://jsfiddle.net/yVScW/1/

```
|     40%       |          60%        |
______________________________________
|----header----|---------content------|
|----header----|---------content------|
______________________________________
```

The idea is for the **header** to take up **40%** of the **row width** and the content 60% of the row width on each row.

This was my best approximation in CSS but doesn't work:

```
.top  {padding:5px;background:blue; width:200px;}
.layer {padding:5px;background:green;}
.header {padding:5px;background:yellow; width:40%;display:inline;}
.content {padding:5px;background:red; width:60%;display:inline;}
```

using this HTML:

```
<div class="top">
    <p class="layer">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    </p>
    <p class="layer">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

So yeah. Tables are evil. But. they work great here. Why don't you just do...

```
<table class="top">
<tr class="layer">
<th>
header
</th>
<td class="content">
content
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And change your styles to:

```
.top  {
   padding:5px;
   background:blue; 
   width:200px;
 }
.layer {
   padding:5px;
   background:green;
}
th {
   padding:5px;
   background:yellow;
   width:40%;
   display:inline;
}
.content {
   padding:5px;
   background:red; 
   width:60%;
   display:inline;
}
```

Comment: +1. If you have a table of information, then you have a table. Tables are great for displaying tabular data. Why is this such a big problem for so many people?

Comment: one suggestion though, you could eliminate the classes altogether by using `<th scope="row">` instead of `<td>` for the header items. Then each section has it's own type of tag and can be targeted based on that. This also has the benefit of being more semantically correct.

Comment: @Matthew Yup, very true. I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="layer left">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer right">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
    </div>

     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

div.layer
{
    float: left;
}

div.left
{
    width: 40%;
}

div.right
{
    width: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```html
<div class="top">
    <div class="layer">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.top {
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0;
}
.layer {
    padding: 5px;
    background: green;
}
.header {
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 0;
    background: yellow;
    width: 38%;
    float: left;
}
.content {
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
    width: 58%;
    float: right;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdKJ3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can change your css to:

```
.top  {
    position:relative;
    background:blue;
    width:200px;
}
.layer {padding:5px;
    background:green;
}
.header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    display:table-cell;
    background:yellow;
    width:40%;
}
.content {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    display:table-cell;
    background:red;
    width:60%;
}
```

## Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yVScW/2/